# Xpages button validation

Tags: xpages, attachment

I am using the multiple uploader from [openntf](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/YouAtNotes%20HTML5%20Multi%20File%20Upload%20control). I want to add an error message if the user has selected the files but not uploaded them.

I am thinking about some kind of *"must click"* button, and if the user is not uploading the files, it should give a message while saving the document saying: *"Attachments are not uploaded. Do you want to continue?"*

How can I check if the span tag : `ynFileUploadInfo` contains something or not? And depending on that, trigger the validation.

Comment: Why don't you use documrnt1.getAttachmentList("AttachmentRT).size() to get the information if a file is uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following client side JavaScript (CSJS) code to your save button:

```js
var files = document.getElementById('ynFileUploadMulti').files;
if (files && files.length > 0) {
    if ( ! confirm('Attachments are not uploaded. Do you want to continue?')) {     
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

It will ask the user if listed (additional) attachments really don't have to be uploaded.

- If user clicks "OK" then document will be saved without the listed attachments.
- If user clicks "Cancel" then document won't be saved and user can click "Upload now" to upload the listed attachments.

Remark: if CSJS code returns `false` in an event then submit and server side JavaScript (SCJS) code won't get executed.

Comment: Knut, I'm using the same file upload control. How would you verify (client side) that at least one file has been uploaded? Thanks !